# Malicious request in log

Tags: linux, security, apache-http-server, php, amazon-ec2

I am receiving malicious request therefore i seek your help i log page urls visited and some of them are like `http://example.com/?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php>` and some are like `http://example.com/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm` and one more like `http://example.com/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&var` what are these user trying to do and how should I improve the security and take precaution

The ip of attacker is `45.146.164.125` , i check it is from russia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like fail2ban for this. These are very common, do not be worried. Just install this thing on top of apache and it's gonna save you alot of bandwidth.

Cheers.

Comment: yeah thanks i will do this , too much spam coming from these webscanners :-(

Answer (score 7):

The first attempt (?a=fetch&content=die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))) is an old WordPress exploit.  If you are running WordPress and haven't updated it in years, do so.  Otherwise, that won't do anything.

The second one (?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm) is an attempt to start a debugging session if you have PhpStorm installed on your site.

The third one (s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&var) is an exploit of ThinkPHP that was patched in 2018.

Comment: thanks for sharing your knowledge